# Soft sound problem on Sony Viao NetBook in GTalk and GMail Chat

Tags: audio, netbook, voip

I have a new Sony Viao netbook and have a problem with the sound - or lack of loudness thereof.

When using GTalk or chat in GMail with earphones all is OK but when using the netbooks' built in speakers the sound is very very faint (also in the GMail Chat test section). I installed the Sony sound drivers and checked all the sound settings, VLC also plays music at an acceptable level but still not as load as my old MacBook did.

All settings are set at 100% - but are still too much too soft to use.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Most netbook speakers are very quiet. Is audio acceptable in any program outside of VLC? I believe VLC has the ability to make sound louder than 100%, which is why it is the recommended media player for most netbooks.

Chances are it's just the speakers.

Comment: The Windows sounds are load enough and can be heard. In the GMail chat test you only hear some buzzing with the voices softly in the background. On VLC I listened to a MP3 at 100% audio - no more - and it was fine/load enough.